# Why the div is not aligned if i give absolute position?

Tags: css

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/5G27g/). I set float left & width(20%, 80%) for the `li`'s. It looks good now.

For some reason(actually, its an another story!) i want the set `position: absolute` for `div.content`.

If i do, the `moreContent` div comes to the left like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/MQ6Rg/).

I don't understand why its happening like this because, i set the parent  of `content` `div`'s
position as `relative`. So, it should be inside the `li`.

I just want to keep the same layout with the `div.content` positioned as absolute.

How to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you position `div.content` as absolute, it then has no influence of the position of the other elements. I'd suggest setting a margin, this will then mimic what `div.content` would do if it wasn't absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmednuaman/MQ6Rg/3/

Answer (score 1):

Absolute position is outside the normal page flow - ie nothing to do with the position of other items on the page.

Comment: not if it has a parent with `position:relative`. [See here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) for details

Comment: I was being rather simplistic.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set an element to be 'absolute', it's basically removed from the page's DOM for positioning calculations. Making `.content` be absolute means that `.moreContent` now has nothing "left" of it to float against, so it moves right up to the parent container's bordre.